# How do I display all contents of List<DayOfWeek> in a string.format?

Tags: c#, enums, tostring

This is a small application for different restaurants and what days of the week they are open. In my interface, I have check boxes for each of the days of the week. I want to output in a `string.Format` each of the selected days(check) boxes. Is this possible?
Here is the code that grabs he checkboxes:

```
foreach (CheckBox cb in grpDaysOpen.Controls)   // Add days of week that the restaurant is open
{
    DayOfWeek enumConvertedSuccessfully;        // Will contain good enums soon
    if (cb.Checked && Enum.TryParse<DayOfWeek>(cb.Text, out enumConvertedSuccessfully))
        favoriteDiningPlace.OpenDays.Add(enumConvertedSuccessfully);
}
```

Here is the current override `ToString`:

```
return string.Format(
    "{0} is a chian of {1} with a seating capacity of {2}:\r\nSmoking is {3}. Last month's sales were {4}, while last months costs were {5}. \r\nThe restaurant is open {6}",
    this.Name, 
    this.Chain, 
    this.SeatingCapacity, 
    this.Smoking, 
    this.LastMonthSales, 
    this.LastMonthCosts, 
    this.OpenDays);
```

I don't know if I need to include any other code with this. If you need clarification, let me know. Currently the above `ToString` outputs

> "system.collections.generic.list`[System.DayOfWeek]"

for `this.OpenDays`.

Answer (score 3):

```
List<DayOfWeek> d = new List<DayOfWeek> { DayOfWeek.Monday, DayOfWeek.Saturday };
string res = string.Join(", ", d);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
string days = String.Join(", ",this.OpenDays.Select(x => x.ToString()));
```

Comment: Pikington Would this be in a second toString in my class? And that would join the other tostring to this one?

Answer (score 0):

Override the ToString() of OpenDays something like below

```
public class OpenDays
{
   public override ToString()
   {
       StringBuilding formattedOpenDays = new StringBuilder();

       //od is an object of type of single element in OpenDays collection
       foreach(OpenDay od in OpenDays)
       {
           formattedOpenDays.Add(od.ToString());
       }
       return formattedOpenDays.ToString();
   }   
}
```

Comment: How do I get the rest of the information about the restaurant into the string?